# Touch events in JQM + IE10 + W8

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-8, touch, tablet, internet-explorer-10

I've found a strange issue when using JQM + IE10 and touchscreeen on a Windows 8 tablet. When using an external mouse och the trackpad everything works as expected but when I'm using the touch screen normal links in JQM are not working.

Having two very basic JQM pages, b.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    this is b.html
    <a href="a.html" data-role="button">link to a.html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and a.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    this is a.html
    <a href="b.html" data-role="button">link to b.html</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Navigation gets stuck on the second one using the touch screen, mouse and trackpad working fine. I guess this is connected to JQM ajax navigation model and the new touch events in IE10, but can't figure out exactly how to solve this.

Chrome is working fine with both mouse/trackpad and touch screen.

EDIT: Might have found a possible workaround, adding this to the css

```
    a {
    -ms-touch-action: none;
    }
```